# My Google play badge isn't displaying on my site

Tags: html

```
 a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=appinventor.ai_fleimlehner.Drafinity&hl=en">
     <img alt="Get it on Google Play" src="/images/brand/en_generic_rgb_wo_60.png" />
 </a>
```

This is the code I don't know what is wrong because I copied and pasted from a badge generator on Google play. The badge isn't showing up but the link is working.

Comment: I suppose that `/images/brand/en_generic_rgb_wo_60.png` simply doesn't exist on _your_ server.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with Google's service, the PNG does not likely exist on **your server**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your link will work, regardless of what is entered as clickable e.g.:

```
<a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=appinventor.ai_fleimlehner.Drafinity&hl=en">
    wibble
</a>
```

The image element (`<img alt="Get it on Google Play" src="/images/brand/en_generic_rgb_wo_60.png" />`) will not work unless, within your `images` folder, in a `brand` subfolder you have an image with the name "`en_generic_rgb_wo_60.png`"

You should look into Relative and Absolute paths if you want a better explanation. The [following link](http://www.chami.com/html-kit/minit/pages/imgtag1.html) is quite an interesting and detailed artile on the IMG tag.

What you can also do is add the image url to an external site (though be aware some sites prevent this), for example:

```
<img alt="Get it on Google Play" src="http://cdn1.tnwcdn.com/files/2010/09/1-500x354.gif" />
```

Apologies if the image stops working above, but you should get the general idea of what you need to do. Find the URL of the picture and use that instead of the routing string.